# Simulink Model restore default configuration

Tags: matlab, configuration, model, default, simulink

I've made some unwanted changes to some reference models of 'sldemo_concurrent_execution' example and want to restore default configs.

I've executed: sldemo_mdlref_util('sldemo_concurrent_execution','close') but it did restore default config sets of some of reference model not all of them! It's strange!

Is there any general command to do this?

thanks